# GARCH model in Python: Iteration limit exceeded

Tags: python, optimization, arch

I have a problem with a GARCH model in python. My code looks as follow

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from arch import arch_model

sys.setrecursionlimit(1800)

spotmarket = pd.read_excel("./data/external/Spotmarket.xlsx", index=True)

l = spotmarket['Price'].pct_change().dropna()

returns = 100 * l
returns.plot()
plt.show()

model=arch_model(returns, vol='Garch', p=1, o=0, q=1, dist='Normal')
results=model.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

The first part of the code works well. I have end of the day prices in a separate excel table and want to model them with a GARCH model. The problem is, that I get the error message `The optimizer returned code 9. The message is:
Iteration limit exceeded
See scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp for code meaning.`

Has someone an idea, how I can handle the problem with the iteration limit? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reading the source code ([here](https://github.com/bashtage/arch/blob/3aa6971d41769fca6b7b02f330fd21d75871c8be/arch/univariate/base.py#L376)), you can pass additional parameters to the `fit` method. Internally, scipy.optimize.minimize ([doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html)) is called and the parameters of interest to you are probably `maxiter` and `ftol` which are part of options dictionary passed to `fit`.
Try manually changing the default values (`max_iter=100` and `ftol= 1e-06`) to new ones that might lead to convergence. Example:

```
results=model.fit(options={'maxiter': 200})
```

Comment: Thank you @Jan! But it doesn't work...I've tried my model with less data and then it works. I don't understand why this happened, because when I use data from yahoo finance, which is much more than my data, it worked too.